# What is twitter:domain good for?

Tags: twitter-card

I'm currently trying the [Twitter Card Validator](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/cards/validation/validator) for [my website](http://martin-thoma.com/jekyll-and-git/).

I did not set `twitter:domain`, because the help text shows

```
RESTRICTED - twitter:domain will be automatically generated from your card's URL.

Not required
```

But I've just wondered if I should set it anyway.

**What would be the effect when I set twitter:domain? To which value should I set it? Should I set it at all?**

(I guess `martin-thoma.com`, but it might also be `http://martin-thoma.com` or `martin-thoma.com/`.)

**Answers that don't cite a reliable source are note acceptable!**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/Yoast/wordpress-seo/issues/438), `twitter:domain` is used to display the text on the button `"View on ..."`.  The validator seems to agree.  Once you enter it and update the card, it changes from "View on web" to "View on (value of twitter:domain)".

Answer (score 20):

The `twitter:domain` tag had since been omitted in [Cards Markup Tag Reference](https://dev.twitter.com/cards/markup) and is no longer mentioned by validator.

It seems to have been de-facto deprecated and no longer used.